# Python/Pandas Change time stamp to include milliseconds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that shows the time stamp like this:
[image]

I need to manipulate this csv in python so I'll end up with a 'Time Elapsed' column with millisecond resolution.
[image]

Keep in mind this time stamp goes longer than an hour so in Excel the time elapsed column just goes back to zero. I don't want that to happen.

[image]

I'm sure I'm not the first person with this issue but before you start flaming me, I have been looking for a few days and I can't find a solution.

That tells me I must be asking the wrong questions. I am new to Pandas/Python and I'm still not familiar with the lingo.

Here is the csv file I am using.

[SampleCSV.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m_-KmNGHjJ_uwK9ABiXcEELt56lDDKlL)

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what the output CSV will look like when opened in notepad? You only show what it would look like when opened in Excel.

Comment: I added the before and after screenshots. Thanks.